# Forms Authentication Signout

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

I've developed two applications using ASP.Net MVC.
I'm using Forms Authentication in both the applications.
In web.configs i set the below properties  `cookieless="UseCookies"`
  `cookieName="ASP.NET_SessionId"` of session state

1. I accessed the applications simultaneously in two different tabs of a same browser
2. In one application I clicked on Logout. It has redirected me to Login page.
3. After doing this, when I try to access the second application, it is giving `Page Cannot be displayed Error` page.

It is accessible after deleting the Session Cookies.

Please give me some inputs on this.

Answer (score 0):

Earlier I haven't specified any name for Auth cookie. 
I tested by giving different names for Forms Authentication Cookie. My Proplem is solved.